# Failed to fetch drpc result

Tags: rpc, apache-storm

I've this problem with supervisor:

```
DRPCSpout [ERROR] Failed to fetch DRPC result from DRPC server 
org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: 
Connection refused
```

What are data? If you need that, I can share it here.

Comment: It says connection refused which means your not authorised to access that resource. Have you checked the IP, port, URL you are trying to access?

Comment: i checked it before it was worked well !

Comment: For me, thrift related errors are usually zookeeper in nature. Is your zookeeper cluster running correctly?

Comment: Yes it worked well but I've problem I guess that is the reason I used old version of storm then updated it to new version by deleting old version folder and installed the new BUT every time I started run new version and zookeeper ,old version folder recreated again but empty and every time I deleting it , it recreate itself again HOW can I delete it rightly?